# Inverse of the negation of the inverse

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm reviewing some old discrete quizzes in preperation for an upcoming final and would like some insight for the following question:

Given A ⟶ ~B, find the inverse of the negation of the inverse.

Okay. So I can do this some extent, but at the last step I'm not sure how best to proceed.

Firstly, the inverse of A ⟶ ~B would be ~A ⟶ ~~B, or ~A ⟶ ~B, right?

From there, I can take its negation, which should come out to ~A ∧ ~B.

What I have trouble doing is taking a statement like  ~A ∧ ~B and turning it into an implication (as the negation rules I have deal with turning implications into statements). Is there a procedure for doing this?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what inverse means, so I'll let someone else help you, but there is a small mistake you made in your typing.  You said $\sim \sim B$ is the same as $\sim B$.  Actually, $\sim \sim B$ is the same as $B$.  I think you already knew this and just made a typo.

Comment: It is unclear from your example what "inverse" means, esp. if it were to be applied to a formula that is not outwardly an implication.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are given the [implication $p \rightarrow q$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)

- Its inverse is $\lnot p \rightarrow \lnot q$
- Its converse is $q \rightarrow p$
- The contrapositive is: $(\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p) \equiv (p\rightarrow q)$

First  find the inverse of $A\rightarrow \lnot B\tag {1}$

$$\lnot A \rightarrow \lnot (\lnot B)\equiv \lnot A \rightarrow B\equiv A\lor B\tag{ inverse of 1}$$

Next, Negate the inverse of $(1)$: $$\begin{align} \lnot (A \lor B)\equiv (\lnot A \land \lnot B)\tag{negation of the inverse of (1)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for writing this. So to clarify, is there any reason why you don't go further and find the inverse of the negation of the inverse of (1)? Is it not possible to do so on something that is not an implication statement? Or maybe I misread what the question was asking?

Comment: The problem is, There is only one (of a possible four) truth-value assignments for A, B for which $\lnot A \land \lnot B$ holds, which is precisely when A = F and B = F. The tree remaining assignments  evaluate to false.  On the other hand Any implication involving two variables is true for three out of four truth-value assignments. Here we end up with a negation of an inverse, with  nothing possible to invert.